# How to successfully 'grunt build' a yeoman project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I used yeoman to scaffold an angular webapp. I successfully created my webapp which runs fine!

I am now trying to put it in production. I register a task build, but unfortunately, I haven't manage to find the appropriate resources that explain in detail how this is done.

So far I manage after running `grunt build` to have a webapp with included and minified css and html files but I can't get the scripts to be included.

Question: what's the role of the build block in the index.html file? The index.html file of yeoman generator comes with some vendor.js etc. Do I keep those ?

I would appreciate if someone could just sum up the steps that must be taken in order to successfully build your yeoman app.

In any case I am posting my Gruntfile and index.html,
This is my Gruntfile:

```
    'use strict';
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

 // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
 require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

// Project settings
yeoman: appConfig,

// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},

// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },  
  proxies: [{
    context: '/gemsbok-web/rest/api', // the context of the data service
    host: 'localhost', // wherever the data service is running
    port: 8080, // the port that the data service is running on
  }],
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
// Setup the proxy
var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];

middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));

middlewares.push(connect().use(
 '/bower_components',
 connect.static('./bower_components')
));
middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));

return middlewares;
}
     }
   },
      test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
},

// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
},

// Empties folders to start fresh
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},

// Add vendor prefixed styles
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 1 version']
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  }
},

// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  options: {
   // cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/common/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
},

// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/common/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/common', //guessed
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    httpPath: '../',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n' //,
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
},

// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},

// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/common/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},

// The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
// minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
// to use the Usemin blocks.
// cssmin: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
//         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// uglify: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// concat: {
//   dist: {}
// },

imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

svgmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.svg',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},

// ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
// using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
// things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
ngmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},

// Replace Google CDN references
cdnify: {
  dist: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
  }
},

// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'views/{,*/}*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'fonts/*',
        'bower_components/**/*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},

// Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
concurrent: {
  server: [
    'compass:server'
  ],
  test: [
    'compass'
  ],
  dist: [
    'compass:dist',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin'
  ]
},

// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }
}
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer',
  'configureProxies:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
'clean:server',
'concurrent:test',
'autoprefixer',
'connect:test',
'karma'
 ]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'autoprefixer',
'concat',
'ngmin',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin'
 ]);

 grunt.registerTask('default', [
'newer:jshint',
'test',
'build'
 ]);
};
```

this is my index.html in the app:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/nvd3/src/nv.d3.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="antelopeApp" ng-controller="navigationCtrl">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">antelope</h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-view="" >
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span> Codean Ltd 2008 - 2014. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-dashboard-framework/dist/angular-dashboard-framework.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/nvd3/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-local-storage/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/sample.min.js -->
<!-- angular-bootstrap -->
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/main/main.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/about/about.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/bluebox.js"></script>

    <script src="pages/dashboard/provider.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/sortable.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/widget-content.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/widget.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/sample.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/sampleModel.js"></script>
    <script src="pages/dashboard/structures.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->



    <script src="pages/dashboard/nvd3chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: In which type of server are you working? Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with MEANjs and the way I've done it is as follows:

1) under your Dev_Server/myAppFolder do ->

```
* npm install grunt-cli && npm install grunt 
* export NODE_ENV=development && npm install // this will depend on prod or dev builds assuming you have multiple configuration ports i.e. 3000/dev, 8000/prod
* grunt build
```

so now you have the /dist folder which you can use to run you app

2) copy this to your Prod_Server/myAppFolder

you can do this with githook, post-receive, rsync, etc.
once there your can do

```
* npm install grunt-cli && npm install grunt  //you can do with -g for grunt only if needed
* export NODE_ENV=production && npm install --production // notice the production option
* node myServerFile.js
```

finally you can create an UPSTART script //assuming your in a linux env so it would initiate your app as a service. There are a lot of things/conf you can do with this but regarding your question I think this could give you a hint of what to do

Comment: Are you assuming he is using a linux server?